# Remove value from Variable

Tags: ruby

This is probably a very trivial question, but..

Assuming we have a variable 'a' that has a value of 10

Then we have a variable 'b' that has a value of 5

Can I remove the value of 'b' from 'a' (leaving 5) and change the value of a each time?

In my head I think of it as:

```
a - b = 5

a - b = 0

a - b = -5
```

etc etc..

Thanks!

Comment: `a = a - b` ? It sounds like you are new to programming. Maybe look up some tutorials? Especially first time ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider this:

```
a = 10
b = 5
a = a - b
```

Now the value of `a` is `5`. This is because Ruby evaluates what is on the right side of the assignment operator `=` first and then assigns that value to whatever is on the left side.

```
#Another way to put it
a = (a - b)
```

There is also a shortcut since this type of math is very common

```
a = a - b
a -= b
# These are both the same
```

If you want to do this a certain number of times, try a loop.

```
a = 10
b = 5
3.times do {a -= b}
# a is now -5
```

For further basic Ruby learning, I would suggest [Try Ruby](http://tryruby.org/levels/1/challenges/0) to get you started on concepts as I mentioned above. (Type "next" there to get started)

Comment: +1 This is the answer my comment wanted to be but I was too lazy to write.